# Html.Kendo().Button() add parameters to onClick event in ClientTemplate

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In Telerik **Asp.Net Core MVC**, I can call a javascript function with multiple arguments with the following (inside a ClientTemplate)

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="mgTemplate">
    <div class="flex-container">

    <a href='' onclick='myFunc(event, 5, 4, "3")'>test</a>

    </div>
</script>


<script>

    function myFunc(ev, id1, id2, id3) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        console.log(id1 + ' ' + id2 + ' ' + id3);
    }
</script>
```

How do I do exactly the same but using the Html.Kendo().Button() control?  Eg the following just calls OnClick with no parameters but I cannot figure out how to configure the Events to pass parameters with the event?

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="mgTemplate">
    <div class="flex-container">

    #if(itemDisplay != "")
    {#
        @(Html.Kendo().Button()
            .Name("1#=itemDisplay#")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-flat" })
            .Content("#=itemDisplay#")
            .Events(ev => ev.Click("onClick"))
            .ToClientTemplate()
        )
     #}#

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the Click Event of the Button and use a JavaScript closure in it:

```
function onClick(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();  
    function (ev, id1, id2, id3) {
        console.log(id1 + ' ' + id2 + ' ' + id3);
    }
}
```